# Huge waiting time (ttfb) on my Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, server, wait

I've been trying to optimize my website performance lately [www.mystartservices.com](http://www.mystartservices.com)  I managed to get from 18 seconds in total for 5.2 MB to 6 seconds for 1.2 MB using plugins, optimizing pictures and minifying css and js scripts. But after a few moments the website's waiting time is at least 30 seconds and i can't find why.

Things i tried :

- Deactivate plugins i recently installed
- Modified the .htaccess
- Restore the database via a backup from the day before

Comment: Are you on a dialup? 18seconds for 5mb is extremely slow regardless of the content.

Comment: no, that was before the optimizations. Last time the waiting time wasn't bad the results were 6 seconds for 1.2MB as i mentioned above.
My concerns are aimed towards the waiting time btw.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, it appears that wordpress doesn't support the multisite very well.. so i modified the wp-config file to disable the multisite features.

Also the plugin

> Advanced speed increaser

kept overwriting the .htaccess file so i deleted it and i tweaked my .htaccess file from scratch.